# Medusa Gatsby Ecommerce Server gives an error on yarn start

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, gatsby

I'm new to gatsby. I'm trying to start the server with **yarn start** after **yarn install** but it gives and error of **/bin/sh: 1: /home/philip/Desktop/JS: not found** It references a different folder.
Bellow is my pakage.json

```
{
"name": "medusa-starter-default",
"version": "0.0.1",
"description": "A starter for Medusa projects.",
"author": "Sebastian Rindom <skrindom@gmail.com>",
"license": "MIT",
"scripts": {
    "seed": "medusa seed -f ./data/seed.json",
    "build": "babel src -d dist --extensions \".ts,.js\"",
    "start": "medusa develop"
},
"dependencies": {
    "@medusajs/medusa": "1.2.1",
    "@medusajs/medusa-cli": "^1.3.0",
    "medusa-fulfillment-manual": "1.1.31",
    "medusa-interfaces": "1.2.1",
    "medusa-payment-manual": "1.0.16",
    "medusa-payment-stripe": "1.1.38",
    "mongoose": "^5.13.3",
    "typeorm": "^0.2.36"
},
"repository": "https://github.com/medusajs/medusa-starter-default.git",
"keywords": [
    "sqlite",
    "ecommerce",
    "headless",
    "medusa"
],
"devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.14.3",
    "@babel/core": "^7.14.3",
    "@babel/preset-typescript": "^7.14.5",
    "babel-preset-medusa-package": "^1.1.13"
}
```

}

It give an error each time. see bellow

```
$ medusa develop
```

/bin/sh: 1: /home/philip/Desktop/JS: not found
Error: Command failed: /home/philip/Desktop/JS Programs/juqwaa/server/node_modules/.bin/babel src -d dist
at checkExecSyncError (node:child_process:828:11)
at execSync (node:child_process:899:15)
at /home/philip/Desktop/JS Programs/juqwaa/server/node_modules/@medusajs/medusa/dist/commands/develop.js:82:42
at step (/home/philip/Desktop/JS Programs/juqwaa/server/node_modules/@medusajs/medusa/dist/commands/develop.js:33:23)
at Object.next (/home/philip/Desktop/JS Programs/juqwaa/server/node_modules/@medusajs/medusa/dist/commands/develop.js:14:53)
at /home/philip/Desktop/JS Programs/juqwaa/server/node_modules/@medusajs/medusa/dist/commands/develop.js:8:71
at new Promise ()
at __awaiter (/home/philip/Desktop/JS Programs/juqwaa/server/node_modules/@medusajs/medusa/dist/commands/develop.js:4:12)
at default_1 (/home/philip/Desktop/JS Programs/juqwaa/server/node_modules/@medusajs/medusa/dist/commands/develop.js:74:12) {
status: 127,
signal: null,
output: [ null, null, null ],
pid: 8605,
stdout: null,
stderr: null
}
Done in 1.72s.

Comment: Would you happen to have a space in your file path structure naming?

Answer (score 0):

To be very honest, I don't know why, but running `medusa start` seems to solve the problem.